# Setting up muli-project web development server

Tags: linux, centos, security, selinux

I'm trying to set up a development server that will be used for several (web) projects by different teams (consisting of different people, some of which may be involved with more than one project). I do trust all of my users, however for legal reasons (sensitive data being potentially stored in some of the projects) I need to be able to limit their access to some parts of the server.

I need to have the following stack:

- `nginx`
- `php-fpm` (via fastcgi)
- `mariadb` as mysql server
- `varnish`

Most (if not all) of the users need to have access to ssh so limiting connections to sftp and jailing them is out of the question. I have figured out the following:

1. `nginx` doesn't execute any arbitrary code hence it can run with permissions to all projects
2. `php-fpm` **can** execute arbitrarty code so it needs to be limited. I decided to run separate pools, each with access *only* to one project
3. `mysql` does not pose any security issue
4. `varnish` is a separate issue that I will have to deal with at a later point

My initial idea was to jail users on ssh connections but that seems like a 'quickfix' rather than a solution - beside it would be limiting and tedious to maintain. My second thought was to use SELinux (which I have no experience with) to limit access to project-related files. I thought the following would work (`margo` is an example project name):

- Create custom SELinux policy (`margo_proj`) that will:

  - Create contexts `margo_proj_t`, `margo_proj_log_t` and `margo_proj_tmp_t`
  - Allow access from `httpd_t` as well as all contexts that the users involved with the project are assigned to
- Have `/srv/www/margo` as `margo:margo` with `775` permissions and `margo_t` context

  - All files inside `/srv/www/margo` that are **not** interpreted by PHP have `775` permission
  - All files that are interpreted by PHP under `770` permissions
- Run `nginx` as `www-data:www-data` and `php-fpm` pool as `margo:margo`, both with `httpd_t` context.
- Add all users that need to have access to the project to `margo` group.

Is this going to work? I have a very basic (i.e. non-existant) understanding of SELinux and wanted to check if this is the correct way of dealing with the issue before I start performing operations that can result in downtime of the server. There is a lot of information about SELinux but I couldn't find anything even vaguely related to my specific problem and most of articles are difficult to understand for non-experienced SELinux user.

Comment: Is there a good reason why all of these unrelated projects must be on the same server? My first thought is to put them all in containers, or virtualize.

Comment: Money. This particular server only has 2G of ram (which may be enough for a few projects initially but wouldn't be a viable long term solution). Also, I currently have only one IP address and additional ones may prove to be costly - any cost increase is not currently feasible. Is using SELinux not an appropriate solution? If so I may revert to jailing the users (using jailkit?) or failing that follow your suggestion (if I can budget server upgrade in).

Comment: If these are just development sites, do you need public IP addresses at all? Even if you do, you can always throw up an nginx reverse proxy to connect to the right container. Better yet, use IPv6 and don't worry about that issue.

Comment: The server is a VPS on [linode](www.linode.com) so it deffinately needs at least one public IP. I stupidly haven't considered nginx for this (many thanks!). I will backup the server, set everything up and see how it holds up.